# rShiny: if ";" is observed in textOutput, iniciate new paragraph

Tags: r, shiny

I pull a `textOutput` from my dataset which includes multiple strings separated by ";". I want to show each string in a new line in the shinyApp.

Right now it looks like this:

```
Baker et al., 2022; Brandal et al., 2021; Jalali et al., 2022; Kang et al., 2021; Luo et al., 2021
```

What I want:

```
Baker et al., 2022; 
Brandal et al., 2021; 
Jalali et al., 2022; 
Kang et al., 2021; 
Luo et al., 2021
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try by adding `\n` after `;`.

Comment: `gsub(pattern = ";", replacement = ";\n", x = your_text)` will add a new line after every semicolon.

Comment: @Gregor it seems that the replacement is working but `\n` not. So it doesn't add a new line after a semicolon. Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Hmm, you could try using `replacement = ";<br>"`, not sure if the rendering will escape that or leave it as an HTML line break.

Comment: @Gregor tried that and it includes the `<br>` in the string. When I use `\n` the output in the app looks like this : `Baker et al., 2022; Brandal et al., 2021; Jalali et al., 2022` and when I use `<br>` it looks like this:  `Baker et al., 2022;<br> Brandal et al., 2021; <br> Jalali et al., 2022`